# AWS can't specify route 53 record without subdomain for cloudfront CNAME

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I decided to host my self portfolio on AWS so I done following steps.

1. Host it on s3 (everything OK)
2. Buyed domain in route53
3. Created A type record to point my domain to s3 (everything OK)
4. Generated public certificate in ACM for domains: *.mywebsite.com, mywebsite.com
5. Created CloudFront distribution and with following setiings

   - ORIGIN DOMAIN NAME: links to s3 (everything OK)
   - CNAMES: [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com), *.mywebsite.com, mywebsite.com
   - WIEVER PROTOCOL POLICY: redirect HTTP to HTTPS
   - used custom certificate made in step 4
6. Created another CNAME record that points *.mywebsite.com to cloudfront url

and as I am totally happy about how things works when i go on website with subdomain like:

- [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com)
- foobarbaz.mywebsite.com
- http://www.mywebsite.com

All of those work great redirect it to my website throught https protocol
but the issue is when I try to reach my website without subdomain like that `mywebsite.com` thats go through http protocol and for https I end up with `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT`, so I tried adding another CNAME record for name `mywebsite.com` and got an following error:

Error occurred
Bad request.
(InvalidChangeBatch 400: RRSet of type CNAME with DNS name mywebsite.com. is not permitted at apex in zone mywebsite.com.)

Any ideas how to get around that issue?

I am not really into networking and configuring those type of stuff, so I would appreciate any tips if I done something wrong.

@edit:
tried adding A type record with name `mywebsite.com` to `www.mywebsite.com` and received:

`(InvalidChangeBatch 400: Tried to create resource record set [name='mywebsite.com.', type='A'] but it already exists), there is already one linking to S3`

Comment: CNAME record can't be used for apex domain. Should use Alias record for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in Step 3). The apex domain points to the S3 bucket, which should point to the CloudFront distribution.

Here's how it should look like:

Route53: ACM certificate CNAME, A record => cloudfront
CloudFront: ACM certificate + alias for mywebsite.com, Origin: S3 bucket
S3 bucket: host the files

Note that only A records (and AAAA, if you want IPv6) point to CloudFront, and there is only 1 CNAME record that is used by ACM to validate the domain.

Answer (score 1):

AWS's [doc](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/troubleshoot-route53-resource-record/) describes this scenario.  ie-

> You can't create a CNAME record at the top node of a DNS namespace, also called the zone apex (such as example.com).  If you're creating a record for the apex domain to point to AWS resources, you can use an alias record instead of CNAME.

[Alias Records](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html)

So, you can use an Alias record with type A instead of CNAME to get around the error you're seeing.

Comment: (InvalidChangeBatch 400: Tried to create resource record set [name='mywebsite.com.', type='A'] but it already exists), there is already one linking to S3

Comment: My response was in regard to the error you saw. In terms of your project, I’m confused about the problem you’re trying to solve. So, your origin site points to a s3 bucket, which is what you want. What Alias record were you trying to create for the origin?  Were you trying to point it at Cloudfront?

Comment: Could you create a subdomain for your site and have that be the bucket name instead and then have your origin and the sub domains your users access go to cloud front?  And then have the traffic from cloud front route to your s3 subdomain?  Then you can have the Alias origin record you want point at cloud front